# Create _id on subdocuments on mongoimport --jsonArray

Tags: mongodb

I have JSON generated from excel via a vb-script. I import it to mongodb using `mongoimport --jsonArray`

It's creating a objectId on each document, but not on the subdocuments. Whats the best way to create these? Is it possible with some option on monogoimport? Or do I have to use an API to do it? Or is there anything I can write in my json to make it generate one on import?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it possible with some option on monogoimport?

Nope.

> is there anything I can write in my json to make it generate one on import?

Not to generate an ObjectId, but you can include an ObjectId in the JSON with the following notation:

```
{ "test" : { "$oid" : "5519e8ac996ef7f4636bfaec" } }
```

This would create a field called `test` with value `ObjectId("5519e8ac996ef7f4636bfaec")`. The value of the key `$oid` needs to be a valid ObjectId.

> do I have to use an API to do it?

Yes, that's what you'll need to generate the ObjectId values. You could either write a small script using, e.g., the Python driver to do the import and generate ObjectId's as part of it, or use mongoimport and then scan the collection and update each subdocument with an ObjectId:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5519e8ac996ef7f4636bfaec"), "a" : [ { "x" : 1 }, { "y" : 2 } ] } 
> db.test.find().forEach(function(doc) {
    for (var i = 0; i < doc.a.length; i++) {
        doc.a[i]._id = ObjectId()
    }
    db.test.update({ "_id" : doc._id }, doc)
} )
```

Note that, unless there's some specific reason to have an _id/ObjectId on a subdocument, like the `_id` is a reference to another document, it's neither necessary nor desirable to put an ObjectId on every subdocument.

Comment: Very good. I use mongoose, mongoose generates a _id when creating subdocuments. It's good to have when you need to do CRUD:s on subdocuments. Thx