# Express.js: the best way to populate mongodb table on start

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I came to Node.js (Express.js) from Ruby on Rails. An there it was pretty easy to do any changes with db via migrations.

My main idea: I have a table like Dictionary (so some of key:values should be prepopulated once on start, if there are no values in this table).

I have two models:

`Maintenance` and `MaintenanceType`.

`Maintenance` uses `MaintenanceType` via `ref`.

**Maintenance model:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const MaintenanceType = mongoose.model("MaintenanceType");

const maintenanceSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    number: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      uppercase: true,
      required: "enter a maintenance number"
    },
    maintenanceType: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,
        ref: "MaintenanceType"
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true,
      required: "enter a maintenance description"
    }
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  }
);

maintenanceSchema.index({
  number: "text"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Maintenance", maintenanceSchema);
```

**MaintenanceType model:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

const maintenanceTypeSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: "enter a maintenanceType name",
            unique: "enter a unique maintenanceType name",
        },
        isDefault: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        }
    },
    {
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true }
    }
);

// Define our indexes
maintenanceTypeSchema.index({
    number: "text"
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("MaintenanceType", maintenanceTypeSchema);
```

**start.js:**

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// import environmental variables from variables.env file
require("dotenv").config({ path: "variables.env" });

mongoose.connect(process.env.DATABASE);
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connection.on("error", err => {
  console.error(` → ${err.message}`);
});

require("./models/MaintenanceType");
require("./models/Maintenance");

const app = require("./app");
app.set("port", process.env.PORT || 7777);
const server = app.listen(app.get("port"), () => {
  console.log('started');
});
```

So: start server -> if 'MaintenanceType' table doesn't have default values -> add some default values (if there are not existing, like: `[{name: 'wheels', isDefault: true}, {name: 'engine', isDefault: true}]`)

I thought about `app.listen` section. But maybe it's not the best place to put `.find` & `.create bulk` actions?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [What is the best method to seeding a Node / MongoDB application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36021906/what-is-the-best-method-to-seeding-a-node-mongodb-application). This might help.

Another approach would be to do this manually like check if there are items in MaintenanceType collection, if no the insert the initial values. Have a look at code below. Assuming you are using get request to go to home/index page.

```
routes.get('/', (request, response) => {
    let initialValues = [{name: 'wheels', isDefault: true}, {name: 'engine', isDefault: true}];

    MaintenanceType.find({}, (error, doc) => {
        if (doc.length === 0) {
            let maintenanceType = new MaintenanceType(initialValues);

            maintenanceType.save(error => {

            });
        }
    });
});
```