# Import MongoDB and automatically include ObjectId in nested documents

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport

I want to use mongoimport on a large json file but I know by default it only creates objectID for the first level documents. I have specific nested documents  that I want them to have an objectID each from the start and not have to do it manually after. Is there a way? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create \_id on subdocuments on mongoimport --jsonArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29354858/create-id-on-subdocuments-on-mongoimport-jsonarray)

Comment: Thanks. I was scratching my head for the entire night.